# SQL Statements in a Windows Batch File

Tags: sql, batch-file

Is there any way to have a Windows batch file directly input SQL statements without calling a script?  I want the batch file to login to SQL and then enter in the statements directly.

**EDIT:** I'm using Oracle v10g

Comment: The RDBMS and version that you are using will probably make a big difference here.

Comment: Also, if you enable delayed expansion , the batch file will be able to send queries that have greater than and less than symbols in them. The point is that you can script ANY SQL query using a batch file without an external script.  I do it all the time.  Also, you can do the same with "sqlcmd.exe" or "osql.exe" as you can do with "mysql.exe".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single command you can use this trick:

```
echo select * from dual; | sqlplus user/pw@db
```

Answer (score 3):

To run something on SQL server 2005/2008, you could use `sqlcmd` command line utility. `sqlcmd -h` prints the list of switches.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No. Batch files by themselves can't do this.

Long answer: You may be able to come close, depending on which kind of database server you're using, and what the capabilities the commandline client provides.

What kind of database server are you using? Oracle, mySql, Sybase, Microsoft, Terradata, ???

For example, with a Sybase database, you can use the isql commandline client to run from a batch file:

```
isql -S server -D database -U user -P password -i script
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) (for sql server) or [System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.aspx) from [powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx).

Answer (score 0):

The odbc command of the [outwit tool suite](http://www.spinellis.gr/sw/outwit/) allows you to run select statements on any database for which an appropriate ODBC data source has been defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://tekkies.co.uk/go/runsqloledb

e.g.
RunSQLOLEDB "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=(local);..." "SELECT GetDate()"
or
RunSQLOLEDB @ConnectionString.txt @Query.sql

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough example script for MSSQL which may be able to be modified for Oracle:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: batch file for sql query
SET STARTDATE=20101010
SET ENDDATE=20111109
SET AGENCYNAME=Agency
SET DBNAME=AccidentDB

SET SQLSTRING=SELECT Acc.INC_ID,^
 Veh.MAKE, Veh.MODEL, Veh.LIC_NUM^
 FROM Acc,^
 lnk_Acc_Veh, Veh^
 WHERE     (INC_NUM LIKE '20115000%')^
 AND lnk_Acc_Veh.link_id=Veh.key^
 AND lnk_Acc_Veh.link_id=Acc.key^
 AND Acc.date ^> '%STARTDATE%' OR Acc.date ^< '%ENDDATE%';

CLS
@ECHO.
@ECHO.
@ECHO DBNAME is %DBNAME%
@ECHO.
@ECHO SQLSTRING is "!SQLSTRING!"
@ECHO.
@ECHO ------------------------------------------------------
@sqlcmd.exe -b -S localhost -E -d !DBNAME! -Q "!SQLSTRING!" -W
@ECHO.
@ECHO Report is done. Hit any key to close this window....
@pause>nul
```